# como passar pelo "executar como administrador"? How to get past "run as administrator"?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

Eu estou tentando fazer um código em python(no jupyter notebook), ai uma das coisas que ele tem que fazer é abrir o aplicativo que eu quero, só que para isso ele tem que apertar em "sim" no "executar como administrador" entretanto ele não consegue fazer isso, eu já tentei fazer ele clicar no botão (da tela) "sim", também tentei fazer ele "apertar" 'tab' 2 vezes e depois 'enter' mas nada deu certo. Ai eu queria sabe se teria como de algum jeito de fazer ele conseguir passar pelo "executar como administrador" sem eu precisar ir lá manualmente, aqui está o código:

```
import pyautogui
import time

#abrir aplicativo

pyautogui.press("win")
pyautogui.write('gens')
pyautogui.press("enter")

#passar pelo "executar como administrador"

time.sleep(2)
pyautogui.press("tab")
pyautogui.press("tab")
pyautogui.press("enter")
```

Answer (score -2):

Tire um print do sim e recorte ele para que fique com o quadrado certinho, após feito isso salva o arquivo na pasta junto com seu .py
E coloque este código

```
Cordenada = pyautogui.locateOnScreen(print.png)
pyautogui.click(Cordenada)
```

Comment: Obs: recomendo adicionar algum time.sleep(1) pois é bem rápido. Espero ter ajudado!